# How do chr() and ord() relate to str and bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the Python 3 documentation on [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to be a little unclear as to how they relate to the two main textual data types: `str` and `bytes`. Or maybe I'm overthinking it.

Here is what I think probably happens, but can you let me know if I'm right?

- `ord()` takes as input a single-character `str` and returns an `int`. The input is a `str` just like any other `str` in Python 3. In particular, it is **not** `bytes` encoded in some specific Unicode format like UTF-8, rather it represents Unicode Code Points in Python's internal `str` format.
- `chr()` takes as input an `int`, and returns a single character `str`. The returned `str` is just like any other `str` in Python, and similarly is not a specific encoding using `bytes`.
- At no point do either `ord()` or `chr()` deal with `bytes`, nor do they deal with specific Unicode formats like UTF-8, they are only dealing with Python's internal `str` representation which deals more abstractly with Unicode Code Points.

Comment: You've got it right. But see also the official documentation for [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

Comment: I'd like to say you're right, but for some strange reason `ord` also works on bytes...

Comment: @Aran-Fey It makes sense, since `ord()` should be able to determine the offset for a single byte from `[0-255]`. Just, for multibyte characters in UTF-8 or any other representation, `ord()` won't work on the full sequence.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I don't think so. Consider `ord(b'\xe2') == 0xe2`. Given my default encoding is utf8, there is no valid conversion available.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.

`ord()` and `chr()` deal only with single-character strings.

Their documentation is quite clear about that:

```
>>> help(ord)
ord(c, /)
    Return the Unicode code point for a one-character string.

>>> help(chr)
chr(i, /)
    Return a Unicode string of one character with ordinal i; 0 <= i <= 0x10ffff.
```

Use `str.encode` / `bytes.decode` for conversion to/from bytes.